# Como hacer que un enum sea extensible en c#?

Tags: c#, enum

Necesito ayuda para mi proyecto de programación porque me dijeron que no debo usar enums porque no son extensibles en c#. Con esto me refiero a que si en un futuro necesitara agregar una nueva forma o un nuevo tamaño, no podria hacerlo, por lo que estoy buscando alguna alternativa a los enums.
Lo que tengo es esto:

```
public enum Shape
{
    Nothing,
    Sphere,
    Box,
    Plant,
    Robot
}

public enum Size
{
    Empty,
    Small,
    Medium,
    Large
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con ser extensible?

Answer (score 0):

Un enum no puede heredar de ninguna otra clase o ningún otro enum.

Ver [especificación ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) (en inglés).

Básicamente:

- Todo enum debe heredar de la clase System.Enum
- No debe implementar ninguna interfaz
- No debe tener propiedades
- No debe tener campos estáticos.

Lo que sí podría hacerse es simular un enum con clases "normales":

```
public class SizeEnum
{
    public const int Empty = 0;
    public const int Small = 1;
}

public class SizeExEnum: SizeEnum {
    public const int Medium = 2;
    public const int Large = 3;
}
```

No es lo ideal pero en algunas situaciones puede ayudar.

Comment: no sabía que la especificación de ECMA se ocupada para C#

Comment: @anonimo se ocupa de CLI, el lenguage intermedio al que se traducen todos los lenguages en el entorno .net